# How can I group this Predicted and Experimental data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data-visualization

The first few points of My data looks something like this:

[image]

I have to group them in Bar plot with experiment number on x axis and the predicted and experimental values on the y axis.

I have seen several tutorials of grouping but the data formatting there is completely different. Is there any way I can group these data in R like I intend to?

My code so far:

```
l1= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
ggplot(mach, aes(x=l1, y=Experimental, fill= Experimental)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Any help would mean a lot! :-)

Comment: Can you provide your imported data as `dput` ? Copy the output from `dput(mach)` in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
mach <- tibble(l1 = 1:6, Experimental = c(14.1, 38.4, 5.3, 10, 2.4, 22.5), Predicted = c(14, 38.5, 4.78, 14.1, 2.45, 22.4))

mach <- mach %>% gather(var, val, Experimental, Predicted)

ggplot(mach, aes(x=l1, y=val, fill=var)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. But not stacked like this, rather grouped beside.

One question, isn't there any way I can do this from directly imported data? I will have to create the variables separately?

Comment: I have actually done them beside too. But was wondering whether I can do something without after directly importing the data.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. What do you mean by importing the data?

Comment: Hello, Sir! I switched to excel for simplicity in plotting this graph. Just few days ago, I came back and tried in R. Your code really worked! gather function solved my problem. Thank you very much!